# How to translate Backspace(0x08, ^H) to stty erase ^?

Tags: linux

I am a newby in Linux. I noticed that the default setting of erase is ^? in Centos.

```
stty -a -> erase=^?
```

When I press Backspace the input character is ^H. How can Backspace trigger erase and delete a character in this case? Which driver translated `^H -> ^?` ?

Answer (score 1):

Those are actually quite different commands. `^H` has been defined as backspace forever, but there is no definition for `erase` which deletes the entire current text string. So the operation of backspace is defined by standard, as are tab `^I`, newline `^J`, and carriage return / enter `^M`, none of which appear in the returned options from `stty`.

Comment: as per `stty -a` `erase` was defined as `^?`. The control code of `Backspace` is `^H`. Why and how can `Backspace` trigger the `erase`?

Comment: Backspace does not trigger `erase`. Backspace, `^H`, triggers `delete character left of cursor`. `^?` triggers `erase`, which is `delete all entered characters`. I don't know if you can redefine `^H` to trigger `erase`, but I also can't see why you'd want to.